# Сделать при scroll пунктирный <path> растущим

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, svg-animation

Ниже то, что я сделал до сих пор .

Это отлично работает, но я хочу сделать анимацию, которая немного сложнее для меня.

```js
// Получить идентификатор элемента <path> и длину <path>
var myline = document.getElementById("myline");
var length = myline.getTotalLength();
circle = document.getElementById("circle");
// Начальная позиция рисования
myline.style.strokeDasharray = length;

// Скройте треугольник, смещая черту. Удалите эту линию, чтобы показать треугольник перед прокруткой
myline.style.strokeDashoffset = length;

// Найти процент прокрутки при scroll (используя свойства кросс-браузера) и сместить тире настолько же, сколько и процент прокрутки
window.addEventListener("scroll", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  // What % down is it?
  var scrollpercent = (document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop) / (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight);
  // Длина offset до dashes
  var draw = length * scrollpercent;

  // Переверните рисование (при прокрутке вверх)
  myline.style.strokeDashoffset = length - draw;

  //получить точку в длине
  endPoint = myline.getPointAtLength(draw);
  circle.setAttribute("cx", endPoint.x);
  circle.setAttribute("cy", endPoint.y);

}
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

#circle {
  fill: red;
}

#mySVG {
  position: fixed;
  top: 15%;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-left: -50px;
}

.st0 {
  fill: none;
  stroke-dashoffset: 3px;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 5;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  stroke-dasharray: 20;
}
```

```html
<h2>Scroll down this window to draw my path.</h2>
<p>Scroll back up to reverse the drawing.</p>

<svg id="mySVG" viewBox="0 0 60 55" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice" style="width: 6%; padding-bottom: 42%; height: 1px; overflow: visible">
  <circle id="circle" cx="10" cy="10" r="10"/>
  <path id="myline" class="st0" stroke-dasharray="10,9" d="M 20 0 v 20 a 30 30 0 0 0 30 30 h 600 a 40 40 0 0 1 0 80 h -140 a 30 30 0 0 0 0 60 h 200 a 40 40 0 0 1 0 80 h -100 a 30 30 0 0 0 -30 30 v 20" /> Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
```

Мой вопрос: можем ли мы сделать линию пунктирной?

Я знаю, что путь растет, используя `strokeDasharray` 
Но все же, есть ли способ достичь этого?

Если нет, то, пожалуйста, предложите другой способ. Я не ищу - `"разместить пунктирную линию над линией, которую вы хотите нарисовать, и придать ей цвет вашего фона"`.

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/45540161/7394871

Answer (score 4):

Есть способ сделать это. Вы можете использовать пунктирную линию в качестве маски для анимированной линии.

```js
// Get the id of the <path> element and the length of <path>
var myline = document.getElementById("myline");
var length = myline.getTotalLength();
circle = document.getElementById("circle");
// The start position of the drawing
myline.style.strokeDasharray = length;

// Hide the triangle by offsetting dash. Remove this line to show the triangle before scroll draw
myline.style.strokeDashoffset = length;

// Find scroll percentage on scroll (using cross-browser properties), and offset dash same amount as percentage scrolled
window.addEventListener("scroll", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  // What % down is it?
  var scrollpercent = (document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop) / (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight);
  // Length to offset the dashes
  var draw = length * scrollpercent;

  // Reverse the drawing (when scrolling upwards)
  myline.style.strokeDashoffset = length - draw;

  //get point at length
  endPoint = myline.getPointAtLength(draw);
  circle.setAttribute("cx", endPoint.x);
  circle.setAttribute("cy", endPoint.y);

}
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

#circle {
  fill: red;
}

#mySVG {
  position: fixed;
  top: 15%;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-left: -50px;
}

.st0 {
  fill: none;
  stroke-dashoffset: 3px;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 5;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  stroke-dasharray: 20;
}

.mask-style {
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 7;
}
```

```html
<h2>Scroll down this window to draw my path.</h2>
<p>Scroll back up to reverse the drawing.</p>

<svg id="mySVG" viewBox="0 0 60 55" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice" style="width: 6%; padding-bottom: 42%; height: 1px; overflow: visible">
  <defs>
    <mask id="dash-mask">
      <path class="st0 mask-style" stroke-dasharray="10,9" d="M 20 0 v 20 a 30 30 0 0 0 30 30 h 600 a 40 40 0 0 1 0 80 h -140 a 30 30 0 0 0 0 60 h 200 a 40 40 0 0 1 0 80 h -100 a 30 30 0 0 0 -30 30 v 20" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <circle id="circle" cx="10" cy="10" r="10"/>
  <path id="myline" class="st0" stroke-dasharray="10,9" d="M 20 0 v 20 a 30 30 0 0 0 30 30 h 600 a 40 40 0 0 1 0 80 h -140 a 30 30 0 0 0 0 60 h 200 a 40 40 0 0 1 0 80 h -100 a 30 30 0 0 0 -30 30 v 20" mask="url(#dash-mask)"/>
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45541540/7394871)